# Is there any way to set a photo as wallpaper with scrolling,zooming permission?

Tags: 14.04, desktop-background

I have set world map as my desktop wallpaper,so that I can learn about the geological location of any country easily.Because when I come to my desktop or restart my laptop I have to watch the map at least one time.But for a big world map my desktop size is not enough.

So,if there have any way that I scroll,zoom the wallpaper of the map then it is easy for me to search a country location.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the best solution to the problem, but it is a workaround for now. This is limited to the actual resolution of your monitor.

You can use `ccsm` (CompizConfig Settings Manager) to setup their "Enhanced Zoom Desktop" feature, which allows you to zoom in on the mouse position with a keyboard combination of your choosing:

1. Install `ccsm` with:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager compiz-plugins-main compiz-plugins-extra compiz-plugins
   ```
2. Run `ccsm`
3. Search for and open "Enhanced Zoom Desktop"
4. Enable the plugin using the checkbox in the lower-left
5. Set the "Zoom In Key" and "Zoom Out Key" to your liking
6. Zoom in and out on your desktop background whenever you want!

Again this isn't the best solution, but a workaround for now.

Comment: Great. If this answer solved your problem, to let other's know this solution worked, please mark it as "solved" using the green checkmark to the left of the answer text.

Comment: Sorry,a problem is occurred when I work in another place not my desktop the program is active and unfortunately if press the corresponding key(for zoom ) the screen is zooming and I can't inactive the program.

Comment: I set the zoom key to a combination like (Ctrl + Alt + Z) and zoom out as (Ctrl + Alt + Shift + Z). Yes, zooming works on any application, so make the keyboard combination something you won't use in another program.

Comment: I think the program is not safe.Because when I faced the mentioned problem I tried to remove and uninstall it, but the program was not removed.And when I tried again again ,my OS was damaged and I restarted my computer.OS didn't allow me to sign in as user or guest session.Finally,I have to take a new OS.

Comment: @BandaMuhammadAlHelal I've used this program for many many years, and it has never harmed my computer. It is a sensitive tool, though, in that messing with settings you don't know can easily mess up your UI. If you have an issue removing the program, open a new question about it, but removing it is fairly simple. Remember that some of these applications may already be installed on your machine, and removing parts that other core system components require forces those core components to be removed as well. You probably removed something you shouldn't have, which is why you couldn't log in.

Comment: you are right.Then how can i remove it in this situation?

Comment: `sudo apt-get --auto-remove remove compizconfig-settings-manager compiz-plugins`